# How to draw the path after a* pathing is done

Tags: java, a-star

I'm writing an a-star pathfinding visualizer with built-in controls to create your own "map", point A being the start, point B being the end, with any walls between. The algorithm calculates the f-costs (using the g & h) correctly and finds its way to the target point but I don't know how to actually draw the path back.

I've linked an image of the result when the target point has been reached, the yellow being tiles that have been calculated, lime being the points that were further calculated.

[image: Example Image of Finished Path]

Comment: You need to find the shortest/cheapest path out of all the solutions.

Comment: Every time you visit a new tile, keep track of its "parent" (i.e. the tile you just came from).  Once you reach the target tile, the shortest path can be found by following the chain of "parents" from the target tile back to the start tile.

Comment: @0x5453, that's smart, I'll give that a try

Comment: For more help with it post [mre]